# How to do modulo in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

How would I do the following in sicp/scheme/dr. racket?

```
(define (even? n) (= (% n 2) 0))
```

Currently it seems like that's not a primitive symbol: `%: unbound identifier in: %`.

This may be the stupidest way in the world to do it, but without a `%` or bitwise-`&1` I am doing (without logs or anything else):

```
(define (even? n)
  (if (< (abs n) 2)
       (= n 0)
       (even? (- n 2))))
```

Comment: In scheme there's a primitive function called remainder, so you could check if a number n is even by doing (= (remainder n 2) 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good practice to get comfortable writing your own procedures when it feels like they are "missing". You could implement your own `mod` as -

```scm
(define (mod a b)
  (if (< a b)
      a
      (mod (- a b) b)))
```

```scm
(mod 0 3) ; 0
(mod 1 3) ; 1
(mod 2 3) ; 2
(mod 3 3) ; 0
(mod 4 3) ; 1
(mod 5 3) ; 2
(mod 6 3) ; 0
(mod 7 3) ; 1
(mod 8 3) ; 2
```

But maybe we make it more robust by supporting negative numbers and preventing caller from divi

```scm
(define (mod a b)
  (if (= b 0)
      (error 'mod "division by zero")
      (rem (+ b (rem a b)) b)))

(define (rem a b)
  (cond ((= b 0)
         (error 'rem "division by zero"))
        ((< b 0)
         (rem a (neg b)))
        ((< a 0)
         (neg (rem (neg a) b)))
        ((< a b)
         a)
        (else
         (rem (- a b) b))))
```

Comment: cool, thanks for that. I found it in the Racket docs, the function is called `modulo`

Comment: you're welcome. i'm aware of `modulo` but i posted this because i think it's a good practice to get comfortable writing your own procedures when it feels like they are "missing". all the best :D

Comment: what about using `abs` for the negative one? Or is the whole point here to use the bare minimum operands?

Comment: @David542 well you can use `abs` but you need to return the correct sign for all combinations `(a, b)`, `(-a, b)`, `(a, -b)`, `(-a, -b)`. i didn't see any easy fit for `abs` but if you do i would be interested in you sharing your solution :D

Comment: if `mod a b == mod (a-b) b` then it should hold that `mod 6 8 == mod (-2) 8`. (that's how Haskell does it, too).

Comment: @WillNess thanks for sharing. I fumbled with my updated implementation a bit. Now I am seeking your enlightenment! Is there a better way?

Comment: you're always welcome (FWIW). :) all I know and can do is look into [Haskell "docs"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) / [sources](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Real.html#line-160). :) :( :) (I've actually always avoided thinking about the bit twiddling stuff as much as I could... :) I'll try to read your code later, and think about it)

Comment: gotta stay high-level 

Comment: if I can help it. :)

Answer (score 3):

`mod` is [`modulo`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html) in scheme:

```
(define (even? n)
  (= (modulo n 2) 0))
```

Comment: For _Scheme_ R5RS and R7RS have `modulo`, but R6RS has `mod` (and also provides `modulo` in the `(rnrs r5rs (6))` compatibility library). _Racket_ has `modulo` (and also provides `mod` in `rnrs/base-6`).